# Serving Alternative Flash Content

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I'm adapting a Flash page to show alternative content when Flash is not available, however, the method it uses is not really ideal for a full-on alternative page with lots of content. Currently, the alternative content is served like this:

```
var hasRightVersion = DetectFlashVer(requiredMajorVersion, requiredMinorVersion, requiredRevision);
if(hasRightVersion) {  // if we've detected an acceptable version
    if (AC_FL_RunContent == 0) {
        alert("This page requires AC_RunActiveContent.js. In Flash, run \"Apply Active Content Update\" in the Commands menu to copy AC_RunActiveContent.js to the HTML output folder.");
    } else {
        // embed the flash movie
        AC_FL_RunContent(
                'codebase', 'http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0',
                'width', '1000',
                'height', '688',
                'src', 'wot',
                //etc, etc...
        ); //end AC code
    }
} else {  // flash is too old or we can't detect the plugin
    var alternateContent =
            '<p>&nbsp;</p>'
            + '<p>This website requires a newer version of the Adobe Flash Player.</p>'
            + '<p>&nbsp;</p>'
            + '<p>&nbsp;</p>'
            + '<p><a href="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflash/">Get the Latest Flash Player here.</a></p>'
            + '<p><a href="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflash/"><img src="images/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Download Flash Player" width="88" height="31" border="0" /></a></p>'
            + '<p>&nbsp;</p>'
            + '<p>&nbsp;</p>';
    document.write(alternateContent);  // insert non-flash content
}
```

The new content I want to serve is much, much bigger than the "get Flash" message, however.

Is there a better way to serve up a lot of HTML (and javascript)? Via an include of some sort? I'm not sure I want to do any sort of redirect - or do I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use SWFObject,

have a div with your alternate system inside in then use SWFObject to load the flash player inside that div if flash player is installed

Look at : How to embed Flash Player content using SWFObject dynamic publishing on this page: http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation

Under : How can you use HTML to configure your Flash content?

```
flashvars devicefont (more info) 
allowscriptaccess (more info here and here)
seamlesstabbing (more info)
allowfullscreen (more info)
allownetworking (more info)
```

You need to feed them into your parameters,

```
var params = {allowscriptaccess:'always', allownetworking:'allways'}
```

Then feed that prams into your loader line

Comment: That only sort of works, but that is probably because I'm not really familiar with how the original flash was put together. When I try it on my test page, the music doesn't load properly and is different to what I'm seeing on the live site. Is there anyway to work with the code above since I know for sure that the Flash works properly with that.

URL to the live site here: http://wot-sound.co.uk/

And my test implementation: http://lisadearaujo.com/clientaccess/wot-sound/indexFlash.htm

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the HotHeadMartin's answer: there is a nice code generator here:
 http://www.bobbyvandersluis.com/swfobject/generator/index.html

Just choose 'dynamic publishing' and fill some text fields.

Comment: Thank you both and sorry for the late response (took me this long to get access to the server). Worked perfectly.

(Sorry - not enough points to vote your comment up, strah)